# decimal emoji with using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, decimal, frontend

I want to change my keyboard character with sad emoji using html decimal code and javascript regex. I just want to conflate that two characters ':' and '(' 
How can I write that emojiSmile regex variable?

Here are my code below.

```
 var finalAnswer = ':)';
 var emojiSmile = /\:+[)]/g;
 var emojiSmileDecimal = '&#128522;';


 if (finalAnswer.match(emojiSmile)) {
   var emojies = finalAnswer.replace(emojiSmile, emojiSmileDecimal);
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to *render* the symbol? Like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kh3x7156/)? Are you trying to check the result in the console? Then, to achieve the same, use `var emojiSmileDecimal = "\uD83D\uDE0A"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually there is no problem with render the symbol but I couldn't conflate special characters. for instance trying to use; var emojiSmile = /:\)/g, emojiSad =  /:\(/g;  but it is render it seperataly and displays just emojiSmile.

Comment: Excuse me, but that is something different from what you posted. Please update the question with the real issue. You seem to want to replace with multiple values, right?

Comment: yes you are right but I've supposed the main problem is not about multiple values. It is about that I couldn't use regex correctly. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: [But your regex matches your string.](https://regex101.com/r/YcnRb8/1) Of course, `/:\)/g` is a more correct form, but the regex you are using is not the show stopper.

Answer (score 0):

It already works as you wrote it.

From first principles, you just need to escape the `)` as `\)` because it's a special character in regex syntax:

```
var emojiSmile = /:\)/g;
```

Escaping it with brackets (`[)]`), like you did, also works:

```
var emojiSmile = /:[)]/g;
```

There is no need to escape `:` or to put a `+` behind it (unless you want to match `::::)` as well).

Comment: But OP already uses `)` inside a character class and does not need to escape it. See [Are “works for me” answers valid?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: the OP's regex would also do the same